# if I want to get some data from APIs by using kafka. Which are the steps for that?

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, streaming

so there is this streaming data and api's to fetch that data.How can I use kafka here?should I first fetch the data and store it and then use kafka?sorry I am very new to this

Comment: What do you mean by "get some data from API's using kafka"? The data will be fetched through the API and not through kafka. Do you mean to get some data from an API and then store them on kafka topics?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Connect and Kafka Streams are two built-in libraries to the base Kafka packaging

If you want to put data into Hadoop, Confluent maintains an [HDFS Connect plugin](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html#quickstart). If you want to get data "from APIs", that's a little vague, but you could write Kafka Connect tasks yourself that are "source connectors" ([there may even be one that exists](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/) for what you want), otherwise tools such as Apache NiFi or Streamsets integrate well with many products (and you  may not even need Kafka using these two, other than it being a persistent message bus)

If you did want to program something on a larger scale, you can look into Spark, or Flink.